# GWT Elemental convert elements

Tags: gwt, gwt-elemental

Is it possible to convert a `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Event` to a `elemental.dom.Element`? Or vice versa?

Same question for events.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because they represent the same browser types and are not wrappers (extend from `JavaScriptObject`, or will use JsInterop in Elemental 2); use `.cast()` or a Java cast.